# 4 колонки на skeleton

Tags: css, framework, markdown

Использую в проекте *skeleton* для верстки.
С 3-мя колонками проблем не возникло:

```
<div class="one-third column"></div> 
<div class="one-third column"></div>
<div class="one-third column"></div>
```

и все замечательно.

Пытаюсь сделать 4 колонки и столкнулся с проблемой.
Они не распределяются равномерно по `row`, т.е. должны занять по идее 25% ширины `row`. Вместо этого они все сбиваются в начало ряда.

Пробовал:

```
one-fourth column
three column
three columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось "костылить":

```
 <div class="one-half">
    <div class="one-half">
    <div class="one-half">
```

И повторил это еще раз. В css убрал отступы лишние. 
Ну а что делать, раз skeleton не позволяет нативно сделать 4 колонки красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
.columns {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">1</div>
    <div class="three columns">2</div>
    <div class="three columns">3</div>
    <div class="three columns">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```